# Не работают кнопки в диалоговом окне PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

В первом файле создается основное окно:

**calcf.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from kinematika import Ui_Dialog

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(523, 346)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(False)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 170, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.toolButton.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.toolButton.setShortcut("")
        self.toolButton.setAutoRepeatDelay(300)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 40, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_2.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 80, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_4.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 130, 170, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_5.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoRepeat(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 170, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_7.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 220, 170, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_6.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 250, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_8.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(354, 250, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_9.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 523, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор физических величин"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Механика"))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кинематика"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Гидростатика"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Динамика"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статика"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Термодинамика"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Состояний"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Процессов"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Оптика"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Геометрическая"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Волновая "))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Квантовая"))
```

Во втором создается диалоговое окно:

**kinematika.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QLabel
import sys


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(463, 481)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 10, 351, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 331, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 211, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 270, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 171, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 320, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 350, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 370, 301, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 390, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 420, 161, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 440, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 351, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 391, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 151, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 90, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 210, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 320, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 440, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 90, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 210, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 320, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 440, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "kinematika"))
        self.label.setToolTip(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Скорость равномерного движения"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите значение перемещения"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите промежуток времени"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Период"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите количество оборотов"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите время"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Частота"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите количество оборотов"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите время"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Центростремительное ускорение"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите скорость равномерного движения по окружности"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите радиус окружности"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ravnd)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.centr)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.prd)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.chst)

    def ravnd(self):  # функция, которая будет выполняться после нажатия кнопки
        a = self.lineEdit.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        c = int(a) / int(b)
        self.textEdit.append(str(c))

    def centr(self):
        a = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        c = int(a) ** 2 / int(b)
        self.textEdit_2.append(str(c))

    def prd(self):
        a = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        c = int(b) / int(a)
        self.textEdit_3.append(str(c))

    def chst(self):
        a = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        c = int(a) / int(b)
        self.textEdit_4.append(str(c))`
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
import sys
from calcf import Ui_MainWindow
from kinematika import Ui_Dialog

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

def openkinem():
    global Dialog
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()


ui.toolButton.clicked.connect(openkinem)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Диалоговое окно появляется, но уже не работают кнопки в нем. 
Но если запускать отдельно файл с диалоговым окном, то все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, **НИКОГДА**. 
**`Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.`**

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from calcf import Ui_MainWindow
from kinematika import Ui_Dialog


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ravnd)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.centr)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.prd)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.chst)
        
    def ravnd(self):               # функция, которая будет выполняться после нажатия кнопки
        a = self.lineEdit.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        c = int(a) / int(b)
        self.textEdit.append(str(c))

    def centr(self):
        a = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        c = int(a) ** 2 / int(b)
        self.textEdit_2.append(str(c))

    def prd(self):
        a = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        c = int(b) / int(a)
        self.textEdit_3.append(str(c))

    def chst(self):
        a = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        c = int(a) / int(b)
        self.textEdit_4.append(str(c))
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.openkinem)        

    def openkinem(self):
        self.dialog = Dialog()
        self.dialog.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**calcf.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(523, 346)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(False)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 170, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.toolButton.setFont(font)
        self.toolButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.toolButton.setShortcut("")
        self.toolButton.setAutoRepeatDelay(300)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 40, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_2.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 80, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_4.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 130, 170, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_5.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoRepeat(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 170, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_7.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 220, 170, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_6.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(192, 250, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_8.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(354, 250, 161, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_9.setShortcut("")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 523, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор физических величин"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Механика"))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кинематика"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Гидростатика"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Динамика"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статика"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Термодинамика"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Состояний"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Процессов"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Оптика"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Геометрическая"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Волновая "))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Квантовая"))
```

**kinematika.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(463, 481)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 10, 351, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 331, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 211, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 250, 291, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 270, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 171, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 320, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 350, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 370, 301, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 390, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 420, 161, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 440, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 351, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 391, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 151, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.label_12.setFont(font)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 90, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 210, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 320, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 440, 121, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS UI Gothic")
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 9, 191);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 90, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 210, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 320, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 440, 81, 23))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "kinematika"))
        self.label.setToolTip(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Скорость равномерного движения"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите значение перемещения"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите промежуток времени"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Период"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите количество оборотов"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите время"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Частота"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите количество оборотов"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите время"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Центростремительное ускорение"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите скорость равномерного движения по окружности"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите радиус окружности"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посчитать"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]